I have an error in my if statement. Can anyone answer?
![enter image description here][1]
Can someone tell me why I have an error?
At first I had an error in the variable because I forgot number 1 and I modified it and found that I still had an error and I don't know why I put everything well and I tried and I didn't understand all the variables are correct and the print statement is co
rrect and the brackets are correct so what is the error?
Please
.I have a simple duty to send a question on this site. I hope my question will not be deleted.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/pBU6BGIf.jpg

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

The operator is >=, not =>. And it is == to compare values, not =.

So, the error in your code is in if statements You're trying to write statement like this: "if(num1=>1)," but you have to write like this: "if(num1>=1)." same goes for another if statement, "if(num1==1)." Rather using two if statements, you can go with using if-else-elseif statement like this:
if(num1>=1)
System.out.println("num1 is >");
else if(num1==1)
System.out.println("num1 is = 1");
else 
System.out.println("num1 is <");

by doing this, your code runs little bit faster and unwanted rendering will not occur
